# Amazon auto start Server via cronjob

Tags: shell, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I have created a cron job to start and stop instance at particular times.

I have set up amazon APIs against user ubuntu. saved script start.sh in home folder

```
#!/bin/bash

ec2-start-instances i-instanceID
```

I placed the job in cron tab.

`0 18 * * 5 /home/ubuntu/scripts/dev/stop.sh`

The script is exicuiting on specific times but the instances are not stopping/starting.
Can anyone suggest a way out.

I also tried setting up the same job in root user that also failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define which binary is executing the script. Hence, try with this:

```
0 18 * * 5 /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/scripts/dev/stop.sh
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know

Comment: I am getting the below error in syslog file
(CRON) error (grandchild #22772 failed with exit status 1)

Comment: Make sure you have full paths in all files and directories indicated in your script, @b00tbu9

Comment: Even with full path its not working.. The script is executing but not starting the server specified in the script

Comment: You should also check if the user running the crontab has permission to execute the script. Try touching a file in /tmp, for example.

Comment: I have checked that also by the touch command. Still it is not giving result.

Comment: OK, in this case it is a crontab configuration problem. Check if your user is in `/etc/cron.d/allow` or `/etc/cron.d/deny`.

Comment: I have already tested the cron with a simple script which was set to run in each minute to create/delete a file in home folder. It was working fine. I am not sure if its because of the environment variables we had to set for amazon EC2 API tools

Comment: Ah, so you mean crontab is working properly. Make sure you have absolute path (I insist on it) and also be careful with binaries routes: crontab is not "somebody logged in", so some environment variables may not be ready for use.